# symfony trying to export a csv file from a link

Tags: symfony, csv

I have this function in the controller, that returns a form with a select box. When the values are selected, I retrieve them with

```
$manifestations = $form['manifestations']->getData();
```

then put them in a repository function that queries the database `$invites = $repository->searchInviteByManif($manifestations);`

```
 public function indexAction() {

    $entity = new Invite();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ManifSearchType(), $entity);

    $request = $this->get('request');

    $invites = null;

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $message = '';

        $manifestations = $form['manifestations']->getData();

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager()
                ->getRepository('PrifProtocoleBundle:Invite');

        $invites = $repository->searchInviteByManif($manifestations);

        $response1 = $this->render('PrifProtocoleBundle:Invite:index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'entities' => $invites,
            'message' => $message,
        ));

        return $response1;

    }
    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'entities' => $invites,
    );
}
```

This function then returns a view `index.html.twig` with a table and all the fields found in the db.

What I want is to export all the queried data `$invites` in a CSV file, by clicking on a link directly from the HTML table.

So I've put an `href=""` link in the Twig file,

```
{% if message is defined %}   
  <div class="pdf"> 
  <a href=""><img height="40px" width="40px" src={{ asset('bundles/prifprotocole/images/excel.jpg')   }}></a>

  {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr class="{{ cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index0) }}">
            <td>{% if entity.etat == 1 %} Actif {% else %} Inactif {% endif %}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.titreGrade }} {{ entity.prenom }} {{ entity.nom }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.fonction }}</td>
```

This is how I use to export the CSV file without the link :

```
$response2 = $this->render('PrifProtocoleBundle:Invite:export.csv.twig', array(
            'entities' => $invites));

$response2->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');

$csvfile = $response2->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="export.csv"');
return $csvfile;
```

`export.csv.twig` file

```
{% for entity in entities %}
  Id {{ entity.id }};
  Etat {{ entity.etat }};
  Titregrade {{ entity.titreGrade }};
  Prenom {{ entity.prenom }};
  Nom {{ entity.nom }};
  Fonction {{ entity.fonction }};
{% endfor %}
```

Can someone give me a detailed solution on how to perform this? Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should simply pass the filter criterias, here the `$manifestations` array as a route parameter, by serializing it first.

Then, you should put a controller like `downloadCsvAction()` handling this route, querying the `$invites` from the database, and rendering your `export.csv.twig` template.

Another option, if you cannot serialize the data in URI, is to create a form with hidden fields containing the data. Then you replace the download link with the submit button of this hidden form.

Comment: thanks for reply, i did this for the serialization:       $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
$normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
$routeManifestations = $serializer->serialize($manifestations, 'json'); according to this tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html                                         i've created the action exportCsvAction() in the controller, but i can't find out how to pass the $routeManifestations as a route parameter after many research! can you show me how?

Comment: First, maybe the form with hidden fields would be a better solution.

But to pass parameter to the route :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-with-placeholders
and
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls

Just used you serialized JSON array as parameter, and unserialize it in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Guillaume's answer is great if you don't mind fetching your data twice. Once when you display your page, and then when you download the CSV. Another way to do this is to cache the answer. I will give an example using memcache (which is what I use).

First, make sure that memcache is active in your php.ini.

Then before rendering your first page (after fetching the data), cache it:

```
$key = "csv.$userId";
$memcache = new \Memcache();
$memcache->connect($yourServerHost, $yourServerPort);
$memcache->set($key, json_encode($invites), MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 86400); // 24h
```

The trick is to find a good key, to add your report to the cache, and then be able to retrieve it. It has to be unique. Here, I assume that you have a user that is logged in, and I use the user ID to create a key. If that is not the case, you could create yourself a token, and pass it when rendering the page (along with $invites). This way, you can add the token to the URL to generate the CSV.

Then, in your second action, where you download the CSV, you just fetch the cached data:

```
$memcache = new \Memcache();
$memcache->connect($yourServerHost, $yourServerPort);
$json = $memcache->get($key);
$invites = json_decode($json , true);
```

That's it. You should probably create yourself a service for Memcache, so you don't have to create an object, and connect everytime.